# Array formula to find clients with a specified service type within a single year

Tags: excel, array-formulas

```
ID  Service     Year    Mark
12    A         2016    FALSE
12    B         2016    FALSE
12    A         2017    TRUE
13    A         2016    TRUE
13    A         2016    TRUE
14    A         2017    FALSE
14    B         2017    FALSE
14    A         2018    TRUE
```

I have a table listing clients, service type and service year.  I am looking for an array formula to find only those clients who had only service type 'A' within any single year.  In the table above I have indicated those lines with `TRUE`.

I can do it easily enough with a pivot table or some behind the scene VBA code but I'm keen to use an array formula instead.  Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need `Array Formula`.

`If` and `Countifs` functions can give you the answer.

[image]

## re-edit

Thank OP and @JerryW's recommand.
I re-edit the formula as:
`=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,C2)=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,C2,B:B,"A")`

Comment: Thanks.  That just needed a small change to work - the last part of the second `COUNTIF` should read B:B,"A".  I like the logic, comparing the count of all services versus the count of a single speficied service.  Very elegant.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the following **named ranges**:

- **ID** being data in column A;
- **Service** being data in column B;
- **Year** being data in column C.

You can enter the following **array formula** (confirmed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) in cell D2 and drag it down to apply to the rest:

```
{=SUM(--(IF((Year=C2)*(ID=A2),Service,"A")="A"))=ROWS(ID)}
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Very nice.  That's what I was trying to do originally but couldn't quite get the logic right.  Happy to upvote your answer but have to say that the first answer with `COUNTIFS` works faster and is much easier to read.  I was trying so hard to find an array formula like yours I have missed an easier solution.

Comment: using **COUNTIFS** by@PaichengWu is quite an excellent non-array approach :) 
 Btw you won't need to use **IF** but simply comparing both **COUNTIFS** is sufficient unless you want to return something other than `TRUE` or `FALSE`.